# Convert the input of an ATX power supply from 110 V AC to 11-14 V DC

Tags: atx

I was just wondering if it is possible to convert an old ATX power supply for my server. It feeds with 110 V AC from the grid, but I want to operate my mainboard directly from the solar battery, which has 11 to 14 V DC.

Could this be theoretically possible?

Comment: They can be bought for a couple hundred dollars and up, depending on how many Watts you need.  Do a Google search on "12 volt input computer power supply" and go from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is theoretically possible.  But by the time the conversion is done, most of the ATX power supply would have been redesigned.  The hard part of it.  The hardest change would be the transformer.  To give an idea about complexity of an ATX power supply, here's a [reference design](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/TND313-D.PDF).

There exist ATX power supplies which run from low voltage DC.  These are used in vehicles and other field applications ([example](http://www.powerstream.com/DC-PC-12V.htm)).  Look for them.

DC to AC inverter could be another option, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, it's theoretically possible in the same way that it's theoretically possible to convert a gasoline powered car to a fully electric vehicle. Rip out all the important stuff and replace it with new stuff and you're good to go.

The magnetics, probably the controller, the topology and many of the individual components would likely have to change.  Not worth it in my opinion.